# Magento 2 : Product URL rewrite issue

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, catalog, url-rewrite, product-urls

I have a Magento 2.1.10 store. I have imported all the products and categories. Now the product url is

> http://www.exaple.com/samplecategory/sampleproduct.html

But I want the URL as

> http://www.exaple.com/samplecategory/sampleproduct

For this I have done the following steps

1. Stores->configuration->Catalog
2. Removed .html from both fieldsProduct URL Suffix ,Category URL Suffix .
3. Saved the config ,reindexed and cleared cache.

But it didn't removed the html from url

Then I have tried this solution 
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3679#issuecomment-311075725

It works for all categories and some products. Now few Products have url like this
http://www.exaple.com/catalog/product/view/id/140/s/water-dispenser/category/43/

How can I make these URL as http://www.exaple.com/samplecategory/water-dispenser ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by using this extension
https://github.com/Iazel/magento2-regenurl

Reference: https://magento2-blog.com/magento-2-regenerate-url-rewrites/